# Simulation - MPI error while running, MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1) - process 0[unset]: aborting job:

Tags: mpi, simulation, abort

I am trying to simulate a simple poly-tropic stellar model using the PLUTO code. I have the code for the simulation written already and just need to input the initial condition. So, what I did is I wrote a python script (I am not very familiar with C as of now) to find the initial conditions (density and pressure) with size 2048 (I am currently doing 1D model) with the radius limit from 0 to 1 solar radius. The files thus created are rho.0000.dbl and prs.0000.dbl for density and pressure respectively. Then I converted the array to a binary file and saved it in the target directory I am working with. Then I restarted the simulation by giving the command:

```
./belt -retstart 0
```

But, then I am getting MPI_Abort error. It reads:

```
application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1) - process 0[unset]: aborting job:
application called MPI_Abort(MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1) - process 0
```

After doing some research I realized the error is due to the initial conditions file I input. But I can't seem to find what is wrong with the file.

Sections of python script:

```
p = np.linspace(0,1,2049) 


#Calculating the volumetric centers (PLUTO grid centers) to assign density/pressure values to

xlin = np.zeros((len(p)-1))
xvol = np.zeros((len(p)-1))
dx = np.zeros((len(p)-1))
for i in range(0,len(p)-1):
  dx[i] = p[i+1] - p[i]
  xlin[i] = (p[i] + p[i+1])*0.5
  xvol[i] =  xlin[i] + 2.0*xlin[i]*dx[i]**2/(12.0*xlin[i]**2 + dx[i]**2)


#assigning the calculated density values to the PLUTO grid

RHO = np.zeros(len(xvol))
for i in range(len(xvol)):
    RHO[i] = rho[np.argmin(np.abs(xvol[i] - r))] #r is the radius values 

#saving the initial condition file in target directory as a binary file
RHO.astype('float64').tofile('/homes/BonnorTest/data/rho.0000.dbl')
```

On running the code I expect to create a certain number of time-steps of pressure and density.

When I run the code without giving `-restart 0`, it is working fine using the initial conditions file already present in the directory (init.c) which is different from my initial conditions. So, the problem lies with the file I am inputting with my poly-tropic initial conditions (rho.0000.dbl and prs.0000.dbl).

I am very new to simulations (I just started). So, I don't know what else information is required to identify the problem. (it would be nice if you explain a bit as I am still getting familiarized with the jargons)

Comment: If you're running in parallel, then all processes are executing `.tofile` and so they corrupt the file. You have to make sure that anything that is not parallel is only executed by one process.

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you very much for your comment. No, I have not yet parallelized it. I am really sorry, I didn't understand the second part of your comment - how do I make sure that anything that is not parallel is only executed by one process? Also I am not adding the python script in the target directory, only the binary initial condition files created in the python script, if that's what you meant to say.

Comment: "how do I make sure": `if (rank==0) do_file_io`